# Why taking the bishop with queen is better here?

Tags: analysis, captures

```
[FEN "rnbq1rk1/pp1B1p1p/5bp1/2pPp3/8/8/PPPNQPPP/R1B2RK1 b - - 0 1"]
```

The engine doesn't want me to take the bishop with the bishop, but to instead use the queen and I don't understand. What difference does it make?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your queen then attacks the undefended white d-pawn.
Also, white is threatening Ne4 (attacking the black squared bishop), and after e.g. Bg7, taking on c5. If black took with the bishop, this would fork the white squared bishop on d7 and the undefended pawn on b7. If black took with the queen, black could simply take the d5 pawn and defend the b7 pawn while attacking the knight.

Comment: You seem to be calling both players "white"...

Comment: Are you suggesting 1.... Qxd7 2. Ne4 Qxd5  ? Does that not lose the bishop and queen to 3. Nxf6+   ?

Comment: No, Qxd7, Ne4 Bg7, Nxc5 Qxd5